# Is it possible to have tag based access using UNITY Catalog

Tags: databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

can we do a tag based access in Unity catalog as shown below

```
CREATE ATTRIBUTE pii
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER ADD ATTRIBUTE pii ON CUSTOMER_CREDIT_CARD 

GRANT SELECT ON DATABASE CUSTOMER 
HAVING ATTRIBUTE NOT IN (pii)
TO NON_PII_ROLE
```

Comment: Yes, I spotted that. I realise the blog was written pre-GA but it doesn't elude to it as a future capability. It talks as if it is implemented using words like 'We’ve also added a powerful tagging feature'. Very disappointing its not there in GA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet. In Unity Catalog it's called Attributed-Based Access Control (ABAC) and it's planned for release somewhere next year - there is no firm date yet, but you can check upcoming product roadmap sessions if it will be mentioned.

Comment: has there been any update on ABAC ever since?

Comment: It was mentioned in the Q3 public roadmap webinar as "coming soon", but I don't have a firm date - please ask your Databricks solutions architect